# Calculate elapsed time since last event

Tags: r, if-statement, time, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains multiple subjects (`id`), with repeated observations (recorded at times `time`). Each of the times may or may not be associated with an event (`event`).  An example data frame can be generated with:

```
set.seed(12345)
id <- c(rep(1, 9), rep(2, 9), rep(3, 9))
time <- c(seq(from = 0, to = 96, by = 12),
      seq(from = 0, to = 80, by = 10),
      seq(from = 0, to = 112, by = 14))
random <- runif(n = 27)
event <- rep(100, 27)

df <- data.frame(cbind(id, time, event, random))
df$event <- ifelse(df$random < 0.55, 0, df$event)
df <- subset(df, select = -c(random))
df$event <- ifelse(df$time == 0, 100, df$event)
```

I would like to calculate the time between events (`tae` [time after the last event]), such that the ideal output would look like:

```
head(ideal_df)
  id time event tae
1  1    0   100   0
2  1   12   100   0
3  1   24   100   0
4  1   36   100   0
5  1   48     0  12
6  1   60     0  24
```

In fortran, I use the following code to create the `tae` variable:

```
IF(EVENT.GT.0) THEN
  TEVENT = TIME
  TAE = 0
ENDIF

IF(EVENT.EQ.0) THEN
  TAE = TIME - TEVENT
ENDIF
```

In R, I have attempted both an `ifelse` and `dplyr` solution. However, neither produce my desired output.

```
# Calculate the time since last event (using ifelse)
df$tae <- ifelse(df$event >= 0, df$tevent = df$time & df$tae = 0, df$tae = df$time - df$tevent)

Error: unexpected '=' in "df$tae <- ifelse(df$event >= 0, df$tevent ="

# Calculate the time since last event (using dplyr)
res <- df %>%
  arrange(id, time) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(tae = time - lag(time))
res 

   id time event tae
1   1    0   100  NA
2   1   12   100  12
3   1   24   100  12
4   1   36   100  12
5   1   48     0  12
6   1   60     0  12
```

Clearly, neither of these yield my desired output.  It appears as though assigning variables within the `ifelse` function is not well tolerated by R.  My attempt at a `dplyr` solution also fails to account for the `event` variable...

Lastly, another variable that recorded the time until the next event `tue` will be needed.  If anyone happens to have a thought regarding how best to go about this (perhaps more tricky) calculation, please feel free to share.

Any thoughts regarding how to get one of these working (or an alternative solution) would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

P.S. -- A reproducible example when the interval between events changes within an `ID` is presented below:

```
id <- rep(1, 9)
time <- c(0, 10, 22, 33, 45, 57, 66, 79, 92)
event <- c(100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 0, 100)
df <- data.frame(cbind(id, time, event))

head(df)
  id time event
1  1    0   100
2  1   10     0
3  1   22     0
4  1   33   100
5  1   45     0
6  1   57   100
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(tmpG = cumsum(c(FALSE, as.logical(diff(event))))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(tmp_a = c(0, diff(time)) * !event,
         tmp_b = c(diff(time), 0) * !event) %>%
  group_by(tmpG) %>%
  mutate(tae = cumsum(tmp_a),
         tbe = rev(cumsum(rev(tmp_b)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(tmp_a, tmp_b, tmpG))
```

The new columns include time after event (`tae`) and time before event (`tbe`).

The result:

```
   id time event tae tbe
1   1    0   100   0   0
2   1   12   100   0   0
3   1   24   100   0   0
4   1   36   100   0   0
5   1   48     0  12  48
6   1   60     0  24  36
7   1   72     0  36  24
8   1   84     0  48  12
9   1   96   100   0   0
10  2    0   100   0   0
11  2   12     0  12  24
12  2   24     0  24  12
13  2   36   100   0   0
14  2   48     0  12  48
15  2   60     0  24  36
16  2   72     0  36  24
17  2   84     0  48  12
18  2   96     0  60   0
19  3    0   100   0   0
20  3   12   100   0   0
21  3   24     0  12  24
22  3   36     0  24  12
23  3   48   100   0   0
24  3   60   100   0   0
25  3   72   100   0   0
26  3   84     0  12  12
27  3   96   100   0   0
```

The result with the second example:

```
  id time event tae tbe
1  1    0   100   0   0
2  1   10     0  10  23
3  1   22     0  22  11
4  1   33   100   0   0
5  1   45     0  12  12
6  1   57   100   0   0
7  1   66     0   9  26
8  1   79     0  22  13
9  1   92   100   0   0
```

Comment: Excellent!  Do you think it is possible to adapt this code to also calculate the time to the next event?

Comment: +1 for this very nice solution. If you want to remove the temporary variable `tmp2` as well, you should insert `ungroup()` before the `select(-tmp, -tmp2)`

Comment: Thanks -- I apologize for not realizing this earlier, but if the interval changes within IDs, the `rev(cumsum(...))` function fails to yield the correct result. Please see my edit in the post above for a reproducible example.

Comment: In both of the examples here, at time = 0, there is an event. When I run this code, `tae` gives strange results for rows before the first event occurs. Similarly, in your examples the last row has an event; `tbe` doesn't seem to work when the last row has no event.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close with your `dplyr` implementation. Try this

```
df %>%
  arrange(id, time) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(tae = cumsum(event==0)*12)
```

Comment: Thanks, nice answer.  The only trouble is that my events are not consistently distributed XX hrs/dys/wks apart.  I apologize for not making this clear in the original question and have revised the example code above to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might be impressed by the compactness of dplyr, but going through a lot of unnecessary calculations really hurts your time performance...

```
> loopfun <- function(df){
+ 
+   event <- (df$event == 100)
+   lasttime <- 0
+ 
+   time <- df$time
+   tae <- rep(0, nrow(df))
+ 
+   for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
+ 
+     if(event[i]){
+ 
+       lasttime <- time[i]
+ 
+     }else{
+ 
+       tae[i] <- time[i] - lasttime
+ 
+     }
+ 
+   }
+ 
+   df$tae <- tae
+ 
+   return(df)
+ }
> 
> dplyrfun <- function(df){
+   
+   return(df %>%
+     mutate(tmp = c(0, diff(time)) * !event,
+            tmp2 = cumsum(c(FALSE, as.logical(diff(event))))) %>%
+     group_by(tmp2) %>%
+     mutate(tae = cumsum(tmp)) %>%
+     select(-tmp, -tmp2)
+   )
+   
+ }
> 
> microbenchmark(loopfun(df), dplyrfun(df), times = 10000)
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
  loopfun(df)   57.356   70.035   95.89365   82.109   96.599 49001.19 10000
 dplyrfun(df) 1494.564 1625.274 1875.85263 1705.722 1877.336 50087.32 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to vectorize it right now, but here's a loop that should be decently quick (O(n)).

```
event <- (df$event == 100)
lasttime <- 0

time <- df$time
tae <- rep(0, nrow(df))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

    if(event[i]){

        lasttime <- time[i]

    }else{

        tae[i] <- time[i] - lasttime

    }

}

df$tae <- tae
```