# Calculate days since last event in R

Tags: r, time-series

My question involves how to calculate the number of days since an event last that occurred in R. 
Below is a minimal example of the data:

```
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("06/07/2000","15/09/2000","15/10/2000","03/01/2001","17/03/2001","23/05/2001","26/08/2001"), "%d/%m/%Y"), 
event=c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0))
        date event
1 2000-07-06     0
2 2000-09-15     0
3 2000-10-15     1
4 2001-01-03     0
5 2001-03-17     1
6 2001-05-23     1
7 2001-08-26     0
```

A binary variable(event) has values 1 indicating that the event occurred and 0 otherwise. Repeated observations are done at different times(`date`) 
The expected output is as follows with the days since last event(`tae`):

```
 date        event       tae
1 2000-07-06     0        NA
2 2000-09-15     0        NA
3 2000-10-15     1         0
4 2001-01-03     0        80
5 2001-03-17     1       153
6 2001-05-23     1        67
7 2001-08-26     0        95
```

I have looked around for answers to similar problems but they don't address my specific problem. I have tried to implement ideas from
from a similar post ([Calculate elapsed time since last event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553638/calculate-elapsed-time-since-last-event)) and below is the closest I 
got to the solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(tmp_a = c(0, diff(date)) * !event,
         tae = cumsum(tmp_a))
```

Which yields the output shown below that is not quite the expected:

```
        date event tmp_a tae
1 2000-07-06     0     0   0
2 2000-09-15     0    71  71
3 2000-10-15     1     0  71
4 2001-01-03     0    80 151
5 2001-03-17     1     0 151
6 2001-05-23     1     0 151
7 2001-08-26     0    95 246
```

Any assistance on how to fine tune this or a different approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Pascal If it makes it easier it would be okay to set `tae` for first three entries as `0` instead of `NA`.

Comment: @Pascal  `as.Date('2001-01-03')-as.Date('2000-10-15')
Time difference of 80 days`. This is the no. of days since the previous event that occurred on `2000-10-15`. Makes sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
# make an index of the latest events
last_event_index <- cumsum(df$event) + 1

# shift it by one to the right
last_event_index <- c(1, last_event_index[1:length(last_event_index) - 1])

# get the dates of the events and index the vector with the last_event_index, 
# added an NA as the first date because there was no event
last_event_date <- c(as.Date(NA), df[which(df$event==1), "date"])[last_event_index]

# substract the event's date with the date of the last event
df$tae <- df$date - last_event_date
df

#        date event      tae
#1 2000-07-06     0  NA days
#2 2000-09-15     0  NA days
#3 2000-10-15     1  NA days
#4 2001-01-03     0  80 days
#5 2001-03-17     1 153 days
#6 2001-05-23     1  67 days
#7 2001-08-26     0  95 days
```

Comment: Just finding this and getting an error on the last_event_date portion of:
Error in as.Date.default(e) : 
  do not know how to convert 'e' to class “Date”

any idea on a workaround? been trying different approachs but don't seem to get the right results. Works in R 3.6.x but not 4.x.x

Answer (score 4):

I'm way late to the party, but I used `tidyr::fill` to make this easier. You essentially convert your non-events to missing values, then use `fill` to fill the `NA`s in with the last event, then subtract the current date from the last event.

I've tested this with a integer date column, so it might need some tweaking for a `Date`-type date column (especially the use of `NA_integer_`. I'm not sure what the underlying type is for `Date` objects; I'm guessing `NA_real_`.)

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    event = as.logical(event),
    last_event = if_else(event, true = date, false = NA_integer_)) %>%
  fill(last_event) %>%
  mutate(event_age = date - last_event)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's painful and you lose performance but you can do it with a `for` loop :

```
datas <- read.table(text = "date event
2000-07-06     0
2000-09-15     0
2000-10-15     1
2001-01-03     0
2001-03-17     1
2001-05-23     1
2001-08-26     0", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


datas <- transform(datas, date = as.Date(date))

lastEvent <- NA
tae <- rep(NA, length(datas$event))
for (i in 2:length(datas$event)) {
  if (datas$event[i-1] == 1) {
    lastEvent <- datas$date[i-1]
  }
  tae[i] <- datas$date[i] - lastEvent

  # To set the first occuring event as 0 and not NA
  if (datas$event[i] == 1 && sum(datas$event[1:i-1] == 1) == 0) {
    tae[i] <- 0
  }
}

cbind(datas, tae)

date event tae
1 2000-07-06     0  NA
2 2000-09-15     0  NA
3 2000-10-15     1   0
4 2001-01-03     0  80
5 2001-03-17     1 153
6 2001-05-23     1  67
7 2001-08-26     0  95
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I was experimenting with rolling joins and found this interesting.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkey(df, date)

# rolling self-join to attach last event time
df = df[event == 1, .(lastevent = date), key = date][df, roll = TRUE]

# find difference between record and previous event == 1 record
df[, tae := difftime(lastevent, shift(lastevent, 1L, "lag"), unit = "days")]

# difftime for simple case between date and joint on previous event
df[event == 0, tae:= difftime(date, lastevent, unit = "days")]

> df
         date  lastevent event      tae
1: 2000-07-06       <NA>     0  NA days
2: 2000-09-15       <NA>     0  NA days
3: 2000-10-15 2000-10-15     1  NA days
4: 2001-01-03 2000-10-15     0  80 days
5: 2001-03-17 2001-03-17     1 153 days
6: 2001-05-23 2001-05-23     1  67 days
7: 2001-08-26 2001-05-23     0  95 days
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to solve it combining some of the ideas above.  The main difference I had with mine would be customers a - nth would have different events (for me it is purchases).  I wanted to know the cumulative totals for all these purchases as well as the date of the last activity.  The main way I solved this was to create an index-dataframe to join with the main data frame.  Similar to the top rated question above.  See repeatable code below.

```
library(tidyverse)
rm(list=ls())

#generate repeatable code sample dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(sample(rep(sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12), each = 4),36))
df$subtotal <- sample(1:100, 36)
df$cust <- sample(rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), each=12), 36)

colnames(df) <- c("dates", "subtotal", "cust")

#add a "key" based on date and event
df$datekey <- paste0(df$dates, df$cust)

#The following 2 lines are specific to my own analysis but added to show depth
df_total_visits <- df %>% select(dates, cust) %>% distinct() %>% group_by(cust) %>% tally(n= "total_visits") %>% mutate(variable = 1)
df_order_bydate <-   df %>% select(dates, cust) %>% group_by(dates, cust) %>% tally(n= "day_orders") 


df <- left_join(df, df_total_visits)
df <- left_join(df, df_order_bydate) %>% arrange(dates)

# Now we will add the index, the arrange from the previous line is super important if your data is not already ordered by date
cummulative_groupping <- df %>% select(datekey, cust, variable, subtotal) %>% group_by(datekey) %>% mutate(spending = sum(subtotal)) %>% distinct(datekey, .keep_all = T) %>% select(-subtotal)
cummulative_groupping <- cummulative_groupping %>% group_by(cust) %>% mutate(cumulative_visits = cumsum(variable),
                                                                                    cumulative_spend = cumsum(spending))

df <- left_join(df, cummulative_groupping) %>% select(-variable)

#using the cumulative visits as the index, if we add one to this number we can then join it again on our dataframe
last_date_index <- df %>% select(dates, cust, cumulative_visits)
last_date_index$cumulative_visits <- last_date_index$cumulative_visits + 1 
colnames(last_date_index) <- c("last_visit_date", "cust", "cumulative_visits")
df <- left_join(df, last_date_index, by = c("cust", "cumulative_visits"))


#the difference between the date and last visit answers the original posters question.  NAs will return as NA
df$toa <- df$dates - df$last_visit_date
```

This answer works in the cases where the same event occurs on the same day (either bad data hygiene OR if multiple vendors/cust go to that event).  Thank you for viewing my answer.  This is actually my first post on Stack.