# Calculating the date difference by group and consecutive ids

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a set of customers, their daily activity log, and if they had and issue raised on their account. A customer can have an issue raised on their account multiple times throughout their duration as a customer and an issue can stay raised for multiple days. I want to figure out the duration that an issue was raised on each account. The dates can start from anywhere and the issue can occur at anytime, saving as TRUE=1 and FALSE=0 in the sample below.

Some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(customer= c('AB','AB','AB','AB','AB',
                             'BC','BC','BC',
                             'CD','CD','CD','CD'), 
                 date=as.Date(c("11/09/2000","12/09/2000","13/09/2000",
                                "14/09/2000","15/09/2000",
                                "13/09/2000","14/09/2000","15/09/2000",
                                "23/05/2001","24/05/2001","25/05/2001",
                                "26/05/2001"), "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                 issue=c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1))
```

I tried making an index counter, along with some other variations found in this thread: [Calculate days since last event in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391333/calculate-days-since-last-event-in-r), but then it doesn't count the continuous days (i.e. AB kept showing up with duration of 1 on each day instead of 2,3,4), as shown below:

| customer | date | issue | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 2000-09-11 | 0 | 0 |
| AB | 2000-09-12 | 1 | 1 |
| AB | 2000-09-13 | 1 | 1 |
| AB | 2000-09-14 | 1 | 1 |
| AB | 2000-09-15 | 1 | 1 |

What I need the output to be something similar to:

| customer | date | issue | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 2000-09-11 | 0 | 0 |
| AB | 2000-09-12 | 1 | 1 |
| AB | 2000-09-13 | 1 | 2 |
| AB | 2000-09-14 | 1 | 3 |
| AB | 2000-09-15 | 1 | 4 |
| BC | 2000-09-13 | 0 | 0 |
| BC | 2000-09-14 | 0 | 0 |
| BC | 2000-09-15 | 1 | 1 |
| CD | 2000-05-23 | 1 | 1 |
| CD | 2000-05-24 | 0 | 0 |
| CD | 2000-05-25 | 1 | 1 |
| CD | 2000-05-26 | 1 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(All methods below assume that `first(issue)` or `issue[1]` is "truthy" enough in its own right, as n `0` or `FALSE`. If your real data is not so lucky, the conditionals will need to be updated (e.g., `issue[1] > 0` would also work here).

## dplyr

We'll use `consecutive_id()` (for run-length encoding) and then group to count the days.

```r
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(ticket = consecutive_id(customer, issue)) |>
  mutate(duration = if (first(issue)) as.numeric(date - min(date)) + 1 else 0, .by = c(customer, ticket))
#    customer       date issue ticket duration
# 1        AB 2000-09-11     0      1        0
# 2        AB 2000-09-12     1      2        1
# 3        AB 2000-09-13     1      2        2
# 4        AB 2000-09-14     1      2        3
# 5        AB 2000-09-15     1      2        4
# 6        BC 2000-09-13     0      3        0
# 7        BC 2000-09-14     0      3        0
# 8        BC 2000-09-15     1      4        1
# 9        CD 2001-05-23     1      5        1
# 10       CD 2001-05-24     0      6        0
# 11       CD 2001-05-25     1      7        1
# 12       CD 2001-05-26     1      7        2
```

## base R

A bit more verbose, same logic.

```r
df$ticket <- with(df, ave(issue, list(customer), FUN = function(z) {
  r <- rle(z)
  r$values <- seq_along(r$values) * r$values
  inverse.rle(r)
}))
df$duration <- with(df, ave(1:nrow(df), list(customer, ticket), FUN = function(i) {
  if (length(i) && issue[i][1]) {
    as.numeric(date[i] - min(date[i])) + 1
  } else rep(0, length(i))
}))
df
#    customer       date issue ticket duration
# 1        AB 2000-09-11     0      0        0
# 2        AB 2000-09-12     1      2        1
# 3        AB 2000-09-13     1      2        2
# 4        AB 2000-09-14     1      2        3
# 5        AB 2000-09-15     1      2        4
# 6        BC 2000-09-13     0      0        0
# 7        BC 2000-09-14     0      0        0
# 8        BC 2000-09-15     1      2        1
# 9        CD 2001-05-23     1      1        1
# 10       CD 2001-05-24     0      0        0
# 11       CD 2001-05-25     1      3        1
# 12       CD 2001-05-26     1      3        2
```

## data.table

Very similar to the `dplyr` steps.

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, ticket := rleid(issue),
                  by = "customer"
  ][, duration := if (first(issue)) as.numeric(date - min(date)) + 1 else 0,
    by = c("customer", "ticket")]
```

Comment: tried the first dplyr solution and it worked. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` oneliner can be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, duration := ifelse(issue == 0, 0, date - date[1] + 1), by = .(customer, rleid(issue))]
```

output

```
    customer       date issue duration
 1:       AB 2000-09-11     0        0
 2:       AB 2000-09-12     1        1
 3:       AB 2000-09-13     1        2
 4:       AB 2000-09-14     1        3
 5:       AB 2000-09-15     1        4
 6:       BC 2000-09-13     0        0
 7:       BC 2000-09-14     0        0
 8:       BC 2000-09-15     1        1
 9:       CD 2001-05-23     1        1
10:       CD 2001-05-24     0        0
11:       CD 2001-05-25     1        1
12:       CD 2001-05-26     1        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::consecutive_id` or `data.table::rleid` is a valid idea, but after that, we can simply use `cumsum` (assuming that your actual dataset does not skip over dates like your example). Or if we have to deal with `date` then we can find the difference between each row's `date` value and `min(date)` plus 1, and multiply by `issue` to assign 0 to the rows with `issue == 0`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ticket = consecutive_id(customer, issue)) %>% 
  mutate(duration = cumsum(issue), .by = ticket, 
         ticket = NULL)

## or 

df %>% 
  mutate(ticket = consecutive_id(customer, issue)) %>% 
  mutate(duration = as.integer(1 + date - min(date)) * issue, .by = ticket, 
         ticket = NULL)

#>    customer       date issue duration
#> 1        AB 2000-09-11     0        0
#> 2        AB 2000-09-12     1        1
#> 3        AB 2000-09-13     1        2
#> 4        AB 2000-09-14     1        3
#> 5        AB 2000-09-15     1        4
#> 6        BC 2000-09-13     0        0
#> 7        BC 2000-09-14     0        0
#> 8        BC 2000-09-15     1        1
#> 9        CD 2001-05-23     1        1
#> 10       CD 2001-05-24     0        0
#> 11       CD 2001-05-25     1        1
#> 12       CD 2001-05-26     1        2
```

It's even cleaner in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, duration := cumsum(issue), 
            .(customer, rleid(issue))][]

## or

setDT(df)[, duration := as.integer(1 + date - min(date)) * issue , 
            .(customer, rleid(issue))][]

#>     customer       date issue duration
#>  1:       AB 2000-09-11     0        0
#>  2:       AB 2000-09-12     1        1
#>  3:       AB 2000-09-13     1        2
#>  4:       AB 2000-09-14     1        3
#>  5:       AB 2000-09-15     1        4
#>  6:       BC 2000-09-13     0        0
#>  7:       BC 2000-09-14     0        0
#>  8:       BC 2000-09-15     1        1
#>  9:       CD 2001-05-23     1        1
#> 10:       CD 2001-05-24     0        0
#> 11:       CD 2001-05-25     1        1
#> 12:       CD 2001-05-26     1        2
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>